# Certain Azure SQL logins do not work with Power BI Desktop, but others do

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-sql-database, powerbi

I have an Azure SQL database, with 3 main login accounts (users). one is my administrator account, with full rights, and the other two are one db_reader and one db_writer login. All three accounts can be used to log in to the database with SQL Server Management Studio. However, when I try to use these with Power BI Desktop, only the administrator login can connect to the database. Using the others, I get the error "Could not authenticate with the credentials provided".

I am using the same machine as I am for SSMS, and I can log in with some accounts on this machine but not with other accounts on the same machine (i.e. it's not an IP/Firewall issue I think).

Why can I not connect Power BI to Azure SQL using perfectly valid user logins? What makes this even more bizarre is that both of these logins work perfectly when I use them as the credentials for a Power BI Service Gateway, *to the same database*.

Other users have the exact same issue on other machines; there is something wrong with these user accounts, but I don't know what it is, and it's definitely not that the credentials aren't valid.

I would appreciate any help here!

Comment: Do those problematic accounts have permissions to iterate through the database objects to list them in the selection pane? https://serverfault.com/questions/586446/is-there-ddl-viewer-role-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you specified the optional database name when getting data in Power BI Desktop?

[image]

When it is not specified, the connection most likely will go to `master` database and your logins do not have rights to read it. There are users for them only in the database, where you added them to db_reader/db_writer database roles. These database roles gives the login rights only in the context of this database only. For other databases, like `master`, these logins has only the rights granted to `public` server role.

So to make successful connection with non-admin login, you must specify the database name in the connection dialog.

Comment: Perfect! That did it. ^^^